# add a newline before a add a text in a file

Tags: batch-file

I'm wondering how I should update this oneliner command to add a new line before the text entry.

```
find /C /I "sapmsTUP 3600/tcp" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\services || ECHO ^sapmsTUP 3600/tcp>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\services
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just echo a newline (with collated `/`) and group both `echo` statements with parentheses so both are redirected:

```
find /C /I "sapmsTUP 3600/tcp" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\services || ( ECHO/&& ECHO ^sapmsTUP 3600/tcp>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\services ) >>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\services
```

Comment: Better use `ECHO/` instead of `ECHO.` (the latter might fail under certain circumstances) and remove the _space_ between it and `&&` (it is echoed too otherwise)...

Comment: @aschipfl: edited (it was a waste of space :)) I didn't know about `echo/`